# Express checkout with payflow pro and recurring payment

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, express-checkout, payflowpro

i am using Paypal manager for the payment i successfully done with credit card payment with recurring payment profile from my website using PayPal manager. but now i want do recurring payment with express checkout using Paypal manager with recurring payment. i am able to do simple direct payment with express checkout using PayPal manager. i found some solution from google that we need to pass two variable

```
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 = "Your descriptor"

L_BILLINGTYPE0 = "RecurringPayments"
```

But i am not able to do recurring payment. I am not getting any error. but my payment have done simple payment not recurring.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There are two things with Express Checkout. First you need to let know the whole process that you will also create some recurring payment profiles.

For that you set BillingType as RecurringPayments when you do doExpressCheckout request.
You will get the Token from paypal and later when user will be back on your site to confirm payment after signing in to Paypal you can use this token to create recurring payment profile the same way as you have done that with credit card.

So after confirming instead of sending doExpressCheckoutPayment you send createRecurringPaymentProfile request.

Of course you can also send doExpressCheckoutPayment if you want also to do some additional payment that is not recurring.

Comment: Thanks for your replay... which procedure you told me i have followed same procedure for the express checkout with recurring payment. as per the guide provided by the paypal.but now i am facing another problem that when i create profile for that time one date want to be set it is start date and that date be future date. i set tomorrow's date. but now how can i know that this profile payment done successfully? another question was after creating profile that user payment will take at every month recurring. but how can we know that user payment for next month is done successfully?

Comment: When you create profile Paypal sends you an answer if it was created successfully or not. Read more about responses from Paypal.

For notification Paypal has system called IPN (Instant Payment Notifications). It sends you info about recurring payment being made or not.

Comment: I am using PayPal manager so i set silent_post url but i am not getting any notification from this url.. then where i will set the IPN url in paypal Manager??